# Prove that two sets are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

I need to show that the relation $A-B=((A\cup B)-(A\cap B))-(B-A)$ is true for any sets A and B. I know that I can prove this through double inclusion. So here is how I did it.
(left to right) Let 
x $\in A-B$ 
$\Leftrightarrow (x\in A) \wedge !(x \in B)$
$\Leftrightarrow x \in(A\cup B) \wedge \ !\ x\in(A \cap B) \wedge\ !\ x\in(B-A)$
 $\Leftrightarrow  x\in((A\cup B)-(A\cap B))-(B-A)$
(right to left) Let
$x\in((A\cup B)-(A\cap B))-(B-A)$
 $\Leftrightarrow x \in ((A\cup B)-(A\cap B))  \wedge\ !\ x\in(B-A)$
$\Leftrightarrow x\in (A \cup B) \wedge \ !\ x \in (A \cap B) \wedge\ !\ x \in(B-A)$
$\Leftrightarrow (x\in A \vee x \in B) \wedge \ ! \ (x \in A \wedge x \in B) \wedge \ ! \ (x\in B \wedge\  ! \ (x \in A))$
$\Leftrightarrow x\in A \wedge \ !\ (x\in B)$
$x \in (A-B)$

Is this the right way to do it? Am I correct?

Comment: You used a string of "if and only if"s.  When you do that, you don't need the "right to left" part, because an "if and only if" goes forward and backward.  So your part of the proof that's labeled "left to right" is all you need.

Comment: Aaah ok I got it. And if I wanted to have both sides (left to right and right to left I should use a string of "implies" ($\Leftarrow$ / $\Rightarrow$), right?

Comment: That's right!  But if you can get away with using $\iff$, then you definitely should to save work on yourself. :)  In my opinion, only use $\implies$ if you have to so it's less work for you.  But if it's easier to always use $\implies$ only and do both ways, that works too

Comment: I feel like I have to upvote the question because your answer is correct. But this is a sin.

Answer (score 1):

I give you another way of proof by algebra. First
\begin{align}
(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)&=(A-(A\cap B))\cup (B-(A\cap B))
\\
&=(A-B)\cup (B-A)
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
((A\cup B)-(A\cap B))-(B-A)&=(A-B)\cup (B-A)-(B-A)
\\
&=((A-B)-(B-A))\cup((B-A)-(B-A))
\\
&=((A-B)-B)\cup((A-B)-A^c)\cup \varnothing
\\
&=((A-B\cup B)\cup((A-A^c)-B)
\\
&=(A-B)\cup (A-B)
\\
&=A-B
\end{align}

Comment: I'll take a closer look at this, even though this is not what I need. I need to do this kind of exercises because I'm taking a course of predicate logic and I can't use  your agebraic method.